# after webpack i got error Cannot find module 'resolve-cwd'?

Tags: node.js, webpack

```
**I got error while webpack** 
error is :
webpack
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'resolve-cwd'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/nodejs/webpack/node_modules/import-local/index.js:3:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
```

please help me to resolved this problem.
I tried this one
npm install resolve-cwd .
still i am getting same issues after type webpack.i also delete node_module folder and package_json_lock file and npm install .after this run webpack still got same above error .

```
node --version
v10.19.0

npm --version
7.10.0
```

Answer (score 7):

I'm not entirely sure why this happened. But I can speculate that it is due to old webpack version.

I've faced this issue right now.
I had installed webpack using apt (on *Ubuntu 20.04.2 (Focal Fossa)*).

Reinstalling webpack using npm resolved the issue.
Steps I followed:

```
$ rm $(which webpack); # removes the currently installed webpack
                       # you can replace $(which webpack) with the webpack location
$ npm i -g webpack webpack-cli
```

Answer (score 2):

Despite installing the missing module 'resolve-cwd' it kept failing with another missing module.

I had to delete the node_modules folder then re-running the npm install command to install dependencies. This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Resolve-CwD. But in my case it was caused by yarn not installing webpack properly.

You have an older version of node so try updating it and see if the above steps are working.

If it's not working then i'd say you try an older version of Ruby until the current issue with har-validator is sorted

In my case the error was caused because yarn was using har-validatior which is deprecated and just couldn't install webpack completely

Answer (score 0):

In my case, showed me this too

[image]

So I just installed the cwd module with: `npm install resolve-cwd`.
And it fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ubuntu just add **sudo** before the 'webpack' command. In my case, this omission caused an error with 'resolve-cwd'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).